# Using Coldfusion to decode a facebook signed_request

Tags: facebook, coldfusion, base64

I'm trying to use ColdFusion 9 to decode the signed_request variable that facebook passes. It is a base64 URL encoded string that needs to be decoded. In order to decode base64 strings one should do:

```
ToString( BinaryDecode( 'Base64 URL Encoded String' ) )
```

When I do this I get the error: input and output encodings are not same.

I took this same string to this website and decoded it correctly: http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. It seems like the built in ColdFusion BinaryDecode function can handle some of these strings. Here's the code:

```
<cfset fb_str = Replace(Replace(ListGetAt(FORM.signed_request, 2, "."), "-", "+", "ALL"), "_", "/", "ALL")>
<cfset jstr = JavaCast("string", fb_str)>
<cfset decoder = CreateObject("java", "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64")>
<cfset result = decoder.decodeBase64(jstr.getBytes())>
<cfoutput>#ToString(result)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: For anyone that's interested the facebook signed_request needs to be padded with "=" depending on the length on the string in order to be decoded properly. Here's a link: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=327043

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the Facebook signed_request parameter doesn't have any "=" padding at end.  It is expecting the receiving end to add the padding before being put through BinaryDecode().

Try

```
<cfset signed_request = listtoarray(form.signed_request,".")>
<cfset fb_str = replacelist(signed_request[2], "-,_", "+,/")>
<cfset padding = repeatstring("=",4-len(fb_str) mod 4)>
<cfset data = toString(BinaryDecode(fb_str & padding,"base64"))>
<cfoutput>#data#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search around the net leads me to think that the facebook response is "base64url" which is encoded for passing in a url.

So, try doing a

```
ToString( BinaryDecode( UrlDecode('Base64 URL Encoded String') ) )
```

And, if that doesn't work, I found this function

```
   <cffunction name="Base64URLDecode" access="public" output="false" returntype="string" hint="Returns a base64url decoded string.">
            <cfargument name="String" type="string" required="true" hint="String to decode.">

            <cfreturn Variables.Base64Decode( Replace( Replace( Arguments.String, "-", "+", "all"), "_", "/", "all") & RepeatString("=", Len(Arguments.String) + (4 - Len(Arguments.String) % 4) % 4))>
    </cffunction>
```

from this url: http://pastebin.com/bFb1bBpU

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Edward, neither one of these methods worked. The first method gives me the same error as before and the second method uses a method call which is undefined "Base64Decode()"

Comment: Ah, didn't look closely.  Base64Decode is another function that is in that pastebin link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ben Nadel's post on how he did this:[oAuth and CF](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2022-Saturday-Hackathon-Integrating-Twitter-oAuth-Twilio-And-ColdFusion.htm)

His code samples show you exactly what you need to do to solve this issue. It took him a while, but it works!

Comment: I don't see the code in that link you sent me. I image I have rumaging through the links. I had looked at this post from Ben: [Ben's post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1343-Converting-A-Base64-Value-Back-Into-A-String-Using-ColdFusion.htm). This method failed since facebook is not padding their string with equal signs at the end. I posted a link in the comments to my answer explaining this. It's facebooks fault =P. [explanation](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=327043)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the game on this comment but I wrote a tutorial on exactly this [here!](http://davemackintosh.co.uk/2011/11/coldfusion-facebook-signed_request-decode/)
It turns out that Facebook don't use a standard base64 encoding and it needs padding out to the right length. Check the link to get a struct containing the data from the signed_request.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that part out too if you look at the comments of the answer. I was pulling my hair for a while on this.