# Difficulty parsing string with Facebook one click sign on and ColdFusion

Tags: facebook-graph-api, coldfusion

I am using using ColdFusion 9.0.1

I am building a site that will use Facebook connections extensively, so we need the Facebook one click sign on. Specifically, to vote on our site, visitors will just "log in with Facebook" and can do all sorts of cools things while we track what they do using their email address.

I am only slightly confused by the Facebook documentation. And with their recent security change, most of the tutorials and help files I find elsewhere are out of date.  So....

I have the single click sign on form on my page. When I am logged out of Facebook, I can use the "log into Facebook" link on my site to log in to my site as well as Facebook.  So, I know the form works and the cookie works too.

From what I understand, I am supposed to read the cookie that Facebook sets in the browser and then parse it to access the info I need.  Here's the cookie for my site:

```
cookie.fbsr_252075631496861
```

When I CFDUMP this cookie, here's what I get:

```
 P2Hlk0UVT2EXc8LiaH48vmL_gI7Y4mwkto0IoSUN9mI.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiIyLkFRQ0VLMC1ibzhqeVhJSzYuMzYwMC4xMzI0MzM5MjAwLjEtMTAwMDAwNTg3NDM1OTY1fFNrYkQ1NU9UWndFMTh3cGE4TUZLZkpLalZzdyIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTMyNDMzNTU2OCwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjEwMDAwMDU4NzQzNTk2NSJ9
```

I have found a few tutorials on how to parse this string, but nothing works. I don't really know if I am acessing the right cookie.

Now that the user is logged into my site via Facebook, I just need their FBID to access their info.  I believe the FBID is buried in this cryptic string.

Can you provide any help?

Comment: It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397747/using-coldfusion-to-decode-a-facebook-signed-request ?

Comment: This actually isn't a a duplicate. The other guy's question is how to parse the string. My question is what to do with the parsed string (when it gets parsed).  I can't figure out what info I need to send back to Facebook to get data.

Comment: If I read correct last couple of sentences in your question is about your problem parsing the signed_request. If you did parsed it, see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get parsed signed_request (stored in your cookie) you can use `user_id` (which is Facebook User Id) and `oauth_token` (aka `access_token`) to get needed info via Graph API or FQL.

Comment: Juicy, where do you get the access_token from?